# Download offsite m4v using PHP

Tags: php, video, curl, download

I want to download files from offsite server.  I do have consent to do so if that comes up :)  What i have is a cURL script that grabs the title and file name but for whatever reason i cant get it to dl the file to my server.

```
$downloadvUrl="$videos";
$file = "downloads";
$fileName=$downloadvUrl;
$header = array(
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
"Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
"Connection: close"
);
$file2 = dirname(__file__).'/'.videos.'.m4v';
$curlObj=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 999);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9999);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, $downloadvUrl);
$response = curl_exec($curlObj);
$return = false;
if(!curl_errno($curlObj)) {
file_put_contents($file2, $response);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it to work by making it a bit more simple.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while(file_exists($target_path).$i) {
$i++;
}
$ch = curl_init("$matches[1]");
$fp = fopen("1.m4v", "w");
if (file_exists($fp)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

How can i get it so the files are upload with different names?

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
$fh = fopen('/tmp/foo', 'w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
```

Change /tmp/foo to the file you wish it to be saved to.